# How to change block size from fifty percents to full in different display's

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two blocks `navbarfooter-linksleft` and `navbarfooter-linksright` Each defined 6 blocks of Bootstrap. If you look at a large width of the screen, you will see that when large screens are aligned one block horizontally.

**Question: How to properly align them (for small screens)  one block
above the other.That is the `navbarfooter-linksleft` must be above the
`navbarfooter-linksright`**

And with each block should be two border between the elements.

```css
.navbarfooter-links {
    display: flex;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.navbarfooter-linksleft, .navbarfooter-linksright {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbarfooter-linksleft {
    text-align: right;
}
.navbarfooter-linksright {
    text-align: left;
}
.navbarfooter-linksright:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color : hsla(0, 0%, 4%, .3);
    margin: 0 15px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.navbarfooter-mainlink:nth-child(n+2):before {
     content: ""; 
     display: inline-block; 
     height: 10px; 
     width: 1px; 
     background-color: hsla(0,0%,4%,.3); 
     margin: 0 15px; 
     pointer-events: none;  
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbarfooter-links container">
    <div class="navbarfooter-linksleft col  col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 no-padding">
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CAREERS</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">ABOUT</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">SUPPORT</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-linksright col col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 no-padding">
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CONTACT US</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">PRESS</a></div>
        <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">API</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know what the parts after `col-` in those classes mean …? If yes, there’s your answer. If not - go read up on these bootstrap basics.

Comment: @CBroe in Bootstrap 4 col means full size of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend you change your structure and use **flex-wrap** property in a media query.
Code:

```
<div class="navbarfooter-links container">
<div class="navbarfooter col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CAREERS</a></div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">ABOUT</a></div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">SUPPORT</a></div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">CONTACT US</a></div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">PRESS</a></div>
    <div class="navbarfooter-mainlink"><a class="navbarfooter-anchor" href="">API</a></div>
</div>
```

```
.navbarfooter {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbarfooter {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink:nth-child(n+2):before {
 content: ""; 
 display: inline-block; 
 height: 10px; 
 width: 1px; 
 background-color: hsla(0,0%,4%,.3); 
 margin: 0 15px; 
 pointer-events: none;  
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.navbarfooter-mainlink {
 font-size: 17px;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
 .navbarfooter {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
}
```

First add bootstrap library. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: ty you sir +1 from me :) I don't know about this property flex-warp that you advice but i will learn and use it in my project's

Comment: @Spectr ;) sorry for typo, the property is **flex-wrap**